# How to trigger react-select input drop down with jQuery.javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-select

I am using react-select for a series of select drop downs on a website that is part Ruby on Rails and part React.js. I want to be able to write a feature test in Capybara that will:

1. Click/focus the select
2. Optionally type in a filter value
3. Pick a result from the dropdown

The end result being to confirm that the value we select is getting saved when the form is submitted.

The select widget is working perfectly in a browser when I click, but I can't see how to trigger it to open to jQuery or other JS click/mousedown/typing events. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

For point 1:
(opening the dropdown in JS)

You will need to pass it a `classNamePrefix='someCustomClass'`

```
<Select classNamePrefix='list' options={[{ label: 'one', value: 'one' }]} />
```

The classNamePrefix is necessary to give you all the class handlers i.e `list__control`, `list__option` ..

Then you'll need to trigger a mouse event on the dropdown indicator:

```
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
  var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
  node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
triggerMouseEvent($('div.list__dropdown-indicator'), 'mousedown');
```

That should open the dropdown for you.

You'll probably want to change the `$('div.list__dropdown-indicator')` to smth like `document.getElementsByClassName('list__dropdown-indicator')[0]`, but I think you get the gist.

For point 3:

Once you've opened the dropdown, you can click on one of the options, for instance like this for the first option:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('list__option')[0].click();
```

Btw: if you don't necessarily need to open the dropdown through JS, you can always add menuIsOpen prop to the react-select component.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having such trouble and could not find this suggestion anywhere else. I am trying to give you a 50-point bounty even though this was not my question.

Comment: happy to help @Ryan :) .

I've actually been through the same when I had to test this, couldn't find an answer anywhere, so had a look over their source code & they do some similar tests there https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/__tests__/Select.test.js (they've changed the testing library to use react-testing-library, they were using enzyme before - diff in case anyone else needs it: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/3989/files ) .

Also thank you very much for the bounty points, really made my day.